# Why doesn't Akka.Net warn if the user tries to go to an undefined state in a FSM?

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net, fsm

I'm now learning Akka.Net and trying to write a simple FSM actor. Yesterday I spent the whole day trying to solve the following mystery. Here's a simplified version of my code so far:

```
public MyFSMActor()
{
    StartWith(State.A, MyData.Empty);

    When(State.A, e => condition0 ? GoTo(State.B) : Stay());
    When(State.B, e => condition1 ? condition2 ? Goto(State.C) : GoTo(State.D) : Stay());
    When(State.C, e => NotImplementedException());
}
```

I was unit testing my class and checking that the FSM behave according to the specifications, except when I tried to check the case in which the FSM should go to `State.D`. The test always failed because the FSM was staying in `State.B`. It took me quite a while to understand that I had not specified that the FSM had a `State.D` by writing the corresponding

```
When(State.D, e => Whatever());
```

But that really puzzled me, because I would have expected the implementation of the Akka.Net FSM to warn me somehow (by throwing an exception or whatever) that I was trying to go to an undefined state. Instead, the FSM just stayed in the current state and I could not understand why.

So my question is: shouldn't Akka.Net warn if the user tries to go to an undefined state in a FSM? Why doesn't do that?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research and thanks to my work colleagues I learnt that returning `null` in any delegate specified for the states makes the event be proccessed by the `WhenUnhandled()` delegate. But it happens that returning an undefined state (not specificied by any `When()` call) produces the same behaviour.

The problem is, I didn't have the `WhenUnhandled()` delegate defined, so the FSM defaulted to the basic behaviour for those cases: staying in the same state and doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to a undefined state, your FSM will be terminated with a Failure cause. You can write an OnTermination() method and check that the termination cause is Failure, like in the code bellow, and handle the issue:

```
OnTermination(termination =>
{
   switch (termination)
   {
       case StopEvent<State, IData> st when st.Reason is Normal:
           // ...
           break;
       case StopEvent<State, IData> st when st.Reason is Shutdown:
           // ...
           break;
       case StopEvent<State, IData> st when st.Reason is Failure:
           // ...
           break;
   }
});
```